# Swift - How to make JSONDecoder correctly parse Date array in hierarchy of classes

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I have two classes one extends the other one (see `DateDemo` and `DateDemo2` below).
If I have a `[Date]` inside the child, JSONDecoder can't parse it correctly.

Here is my test class `DateDecodeTests` that I run on iOS.
Basically I just trying the `testDateDecodingWithHierarchy` test method to pass returning a `eventsDateTimes3` different from `nil`.

From these two tests it can be seen that `testDateDecoding` works perfectly and contrariwise `testDateDecodingWithHierarchy` has a problem in parsing the `eventsDateTimes3` field (which is a field owned only by the child class `DateDemo2`).

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

class DateDecodeTests: XCTestCase {

    class DateDemo :Decodable {
        var dates : [Date]
        var eventsDateTimes : [Date]?
        var eventsDateTimes2 : [Date]?
    }

    class DateDemo2 : DateDemo {
        var eventsDateTimes3 : [Date]?
    }

    func testDateDecoding() throws {

        let json = """
        {
            "dates": ["2018-10-17T23:00:00.000+01:00", "2018-10-18T00:30:00.000+01:00"],
            "eventsDateTimes": ["2018-10-18T22:00:00.000+02:00", "2018-10-31T00:30:00.000+01:00", "2018-11-08T20:00:00.000+01:00"],
            "eventsDateTimes2": [],
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)!

        let decoder : JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder.myDefaultJsonDecoder

        let date = try decoder.decode(DateDemo.self, from: json)

        print(date.dates)
        print(date.eventsDateTimes)
        print(date.eventsDateTimes2)

        // It prints out:
        // [2018-10-17 22:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-17 23:30:00 +0000]
        // Optional([2018-10-18 20:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-30 23:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 19:00:00 +0000])
        // Optional([])

    }

    func testDateDecodingWithHierarchy() throws {

        let json = """
        {
            "dates": ["2018-10-17T23:00:00.000+01:00", "2018-10-18T00:30:00.000+01:00"],
            "eventsDateTimes": ["2018-10-18T22:00:00.000+02:00", "2018-10-31T00:30:00.000+01:00", "2018-11-08T20:00:00.000+01:00"],
            "eventsDateTimes2": [],
            "eventsDateTimes3": ["2018-10-18T22:00:00.000+02:00", "2018-10-31T00:30:00.000+01:00", "2018-11-08T20:00:00.000+01:00"],
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)!

        let decoder : JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder.myDefaultJsonDecoder

        let date = try decoder.decode(DateDemo2.self, from: json)

        print(date.dates)
        print(date.eventsDateTimes)
        print(date.eventsDateTimes2)
        print(date.eventsDateTimes3)

        // It prints out:
        // [2018-10-17 22:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-17 23:30:00 +0000]
        // Optional([2018-10-18 20:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-30 23:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 19:00:00 +0000])
        // Optional([])
        // nil ---> ??? Why is this nil?

        assert(date.eventsDateTimes3 != nil, "eventsDateTimes3 must not be nil")
    }

}

extension JSONDecoder {
    static var myDefaultJsonDecoder: JSONDecoder {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.myDefaultDateFormatter)
        return decoder
    }
}

extension DateFormatter {
    static var myDefaultDateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
        return formatter
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if you could subclass like that, but you can't. See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5125. A subclass of a Decodable class doesn't decode properly. Don't do that. Just move `var eventsDateTimes3` up into DateDemo and use that ("flatify", as the bug report puts it).

Comment: I'm sure @ItaiFerber could comment on this (he's probably answered it elsewhere already).

Comment: Yeah flatify does work, I hope there will be soon another workaround that does not broke the basis of OOP, for now I will follow your advice, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateDemo` conforms to `Decodable` but doesn't explicitly define `init(from:Decoder) throws`. So Swift synthesizes a definition of `init(from:Decoder) throws` that decodes the properties of `DateDemo`.

`DateDemo2` inherits from `DateDemo`. It adds one property: `eventsDateTimes3`. It does not define any initializers. Normally, Swift would complain about the lack of initializers. However, because the new property is both `var` and optional, Swift considers it to have a default value of `nil`.

Since the only new property of `DateDemo2` has a default value, Swift applies [automatic initializer inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222). Your `DateDemo2` class inherits all of its superclass's designated initializers. There is only one initializer to inherit: the synthesized `Decodable` initializer. The inherited initializer initializes `eventsDateTimes3` to its default value (`nil`). That is just how inherited initializers work.

You were hoping that Swift would synthesize a `Decodable` initializer for `DateDemo2` as it did for `DateDemo`, by initializing `eventsDateTimes3` from the `Decoder`. But Swift does not do that. Here's what Itai Ferber (the Apple programmer responsible for the `Coding` implementation) said on the [Swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/inheriting-from-a-codable-class/14874/7?u=mayoff):

> This case would be improved if the compiler could synthesize `SuperClass.init(from:)` instead of inheriting, but it won't be able to without a refactor of Swift's protocol conformance and inheritance system (and without syntax to disambiguate between "I'm not providing an implementation because I'd like to inherit" vs. "I'm not providing an implementation because I'd like to synthesize")

In other words, there are two legitimate cases:

1. You want your subclass to inherit its superclass's initializer and default-initialize the new properties.
2. You want the compiler to synthesize an initializer that decodes the new properties.

You always get #1 now because that is all there was before the `Codable` system was added, and because there is no syntax for telling the compiler you want #2 instead.

So you need to implement `init(from:)` yourself in `DateDemo2`. Here's an implementation:

```
class DateDemo2 : DateDemo {
    var eventsDateTimes3 : [Date]?

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        eventsDateTimes3 = try container.decode([Date]?.self, forKey: .eventsDateTimes3)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case eventsDateTimes3
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, what my comment should have said is "A subclass of a Decodable class doesn't _automagically_ decode properly" (i.e. because you don't get magical autosynthesis). I'm a little surprised that even at this late date, when this issue is so clearly know, that we don't get at least a warning.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case, but another work around is to put the common attributes in a protocol and use that in place of inheritance. (also allows you to use structs )

```
protocol AnyDateHolder: Decodable {
    var dates : [Date] {get set}
    var eventsDateTimes : [Date]? {get set}
    var eventsDateTimes2 : [Date]? {get set}
}

class DateDemo: AnyDateHolder {
    var dates : [Date]
    var eventsDateTimes : [Date]?
    var eventsDateTimes2 : [Date]?
}

class DateDemo2: AnyDateHolder {
    var dates : [Date]
    var eventsDateTimes : [Date]?
    var eventsDateTimes2 : [Date]?
    var eventsDateTimes3 : [Date]?
}
```

With your second test it prints:

```
[2018-10-17 22:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-17 23:30:00 +0000]
Optional([2018-10-18 20:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-30 23:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 19:00:00 +0000])
Optional([])
Optional([2018-10-18 20:00:00 +0000, 2018-10-30 23:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 19:00:00 +0000])
```